# Custom filter provider web part and multiple values

Tags: web-part, filter

I'm trying to build a custom filter provider that can detect the user language (the language selected in SharePoint by the user) and provide it as a filter.

As a language can be represented in many ways (ex: French can be written  "fr", "fre", "fra", "français", "french", "1036"), I want to push multiple values in my web part.

By now, I have written this code :

```
[ToolboxItemAttribute(false)]
public class LanguageFilterProviderWebPart : WebPart, ITransformableFilterValues
{
    public virtual bool AllowAllValue
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public virtual bool AllowEmptyValue
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public virtual bool AllowMultipleValues
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public virtual string ParameterName
    {
        get { return this.Title; }
    }

    public virtual ReadOnlyCollection<string> ParameterValues
    {
        get { return new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(m_Values); }
    }

    private string[] m_Values;

    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        var userCulture = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture;
        var lcid = userCulture.LCID;
        switch (lcid)
        {
            case 1036:
                m_Values = new string[] { "fr", "fre", "fra", "français", "french", "1036" };
                break;

            case 1033:
            default: // Default to english
                m_Values = new string[] { "en", "eng", "enu", "anglais", "english", "1033" };
                break;
        }
        base.OnInit(e);
    }

    [System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.ConnectionProvider("User's language filter", "ITransformableFilterValues", AllowsMultipleConnections = true)]
    public ITransformableFilterValues SetConnectionInterface()
    {
        return this;
    }

    [Browsable(false)]
    public override bool Hidden
    {
        get
        {
            if (base.WebPartManager != null)
            {
                return !base.WebPartManager.DisplayMode.AllowPageDesign;
            }
            return base.Hidden;
        }
        set
        {
            base.Hidden = value;
        }
    }
}
```

The language detection is working, but only the first value is passed as filter. In my case, only items with `fr` or `en` are shown, even if other matching values exists.

What is missing or wrong in my code?